# Checking a particular entry in database and getting id of it if it exists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Before you answer:**

I am using `flask-sqlalchemy` library for Python `app.py` webapp, and a SQLite database referred as `sqlite:///mydb.db`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlachemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI] = 'sqlite:///mydb.db'

db = SQLAlchemy (app)

class Mydb(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
 userName = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False, unique = True)
 pwd = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
 created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

...... AND IT GOES ON FURTHER
```

I've created a database, and it is getting entries from a HTML form. The database is working fine and it has few entries.

**Question**

How can I grab `ID(/IDs)` of a particular entry inside database if I know that(/those) entry(entries) exists(/exist) in our database? ID is defined as

```
db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
```

It would be great if no new library is used for it.

I know

```
bool(Model.query.filter_by(user='John').first())
```

will tell me if user with the name of 'John' exists but how can I get ID(/IDs) of this entry after knowing that it exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.query.filter_by(user='John').first()` returns the object in the database:

```
user = Model.query.filter_by(user='John').first()
if user:
    id = user.id
```